# Sharepoint Designer 2010 doesn't find my Site objects

Tags: sharepoint-designer

My sharepoint designer 2010 shows no items under Lists and Libraries even though I can see them under All files and the site is functioning fine. There's also nothing listed If I try to create a new list or library. Additionally, I'm unable to retrieve properties for any list or library.

The site was upgraded from wss 3.0 to spf 2010 running on windows 2008 with sql 2008 r2 using the database attach method.

Where does SPD2010 get this information from? is there an XML file I can edit somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that there was a left-over bit from a U2U Caml query builder feature installed on the site. It was a folder left from the wss 3.0 site. I deleted the folder and bada-bing all my site objects became visible.